# Stack smashing detected while implementing stack using array

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm trying to implement a stack using an array in C.

It shows "stack smashing detected" an error while running. How can I fix it?

Also, can you explain why stack smashing occurs?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 1

void push(int stack[], int *top, int data){
    
    if(*top<MAX){
        *top = *top + 1;
        stack[*top] = data;

        printf("Pushed element %d\n",data);

        return;
    }

    printf("Push failed : Stack overflow\n");
}


int main(){
    int stack[MAX];
    int top = -1;

    push(stack, &top, 1);
    push(stack, &top, 2);
    push(stack, &top, 3);
    push(stack, &top, 3);

    // display(stack,top);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aanand S, do you want `MAX` to represent the maximum elements in the stack or the maximum value for the `top` variable?

Comment: ```MAX``` is the maximum elements in the stack

Comment: OK. Then `#define TOP_MAX (MAX - 1)` `if (*top < TOP_MAX) {` makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

The check for reaching the top of the stack is wrong.

You have `*top < MAX`.

The problem with that is that it makes the check using the *old* value of `*top`. In the first call to `push` it will be equal to `-1`, which is indeed less than `1` (the value of `MAX`). The problem comes with the second call where `*top` is equal to `0`, which is *still* less than `1` and so you increase `*top` to `1` and use it as an (out of bounds) index.

You need to check the value of `*top + 1`:

```
if (*top + 1 < MAX) { ... }
```

Comment: Minor: Curious that you did not suggest `*top < MAX - 1` (tighter emitted code and allows for a 1 greater `MAX` and still do `int` math).